# Insert and/or Upsert not working

Tags: apex, soql, upsert

I've created two different classes, each writing to a different homebrew table and I'm not having any problem inserting in one of them, but I can't seem to get the other class to insert records into the other table,  neither insert nor upsert seems to work, but I get no errors!

The class I'm testing is a global class that implements Schedulable, in a full clone Sandbox and for this test I'm just running it through the Developer Console as a test function.  In essence here's a snippet of code that's executing, ... but isn't working!

---

```
    for (Item item : items.values()) {                      // all remaining records are new entries
        AccountChangeReport__c acrRec = new AccountChangeReport__c(
            sourceId__c = item.sourceId,
            source__c   = item.source,
            name__c     = item.name,
            status__c   = 'New',
            lastSunProcessed__c = dSun);
        acrRecs.add(acrRec);
    }

    try {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'recs to upsert ' + acrRecs.size());
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, acrRecs.get(0));
        upsert acrRecs sourceId__c;                         // this isn't working, but no errors occur
        //insert acrRecs                                    // tried this too, still doesn't work

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'recs to delete ' + toDelete.size());
        delete toDelete;
    }
    Catch(DmlException e) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, e.getMessage());
    }
```

---

and the relevant part of the logs are showing this:

> 11:07:44.0 (28215843)|USER_DEBUG|[107]|DEBUG|recs to upsert 20
>   11:07:44.0 (28222867)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[109] 11:07:44.0
>   (28246596)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[109]|Bytes:24 11:07:44.0
>   (28288041)|USER_DEBUG|[109]|DEBUG|AccountChangeReport__c:{sourceId__c=0010P00001oFPEFQA4,
>   source__c=Account, name__c=Cowen, status__c=New,
>   lastSunProcessed__c=2017-11-26 00:00:00} 11:07:44.0
>   (28296140)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[110] 11:07:44.0
>   (28299398)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[110]|Bytes:22 11:07:44.0
>   (28302854)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[110]|Bytes:11 11:07:44.0
>   (28359170)|DML_BEGIN|[110]|Op:Upsert|Type:AccountChangeReport__c|Rows:20
>   11:07:44.0 (28382074)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:84 11:07:44.0
>   (96690508)|DML_END|[110] 11:07:44.0
>   (96764187)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:84 11:07:44.0
>   (96787025)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[112] 11:07:44.0
>   (96802944)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[112]|Bytes:15 11:07:44.0
>   (96879520)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[112]|Bytes:1 11:07:44.0
>   (96893734)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[112]|Bytes:16 11:07:44.0
>   (96919093)|USER_DEBUG|[112]|DEBUG|recs to delete 0 11:07:44.0
>   (96925926)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[113] 11:07:44.0
>   (96994758)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4 11:07:44.0
>   (97009424)|METHOD_EXIT|[11]|01p0x0000004riu|AccountChangeReporter.execute(System.SchedulableContext)
>   11:07:44.97 (97024002)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE 11:07:44.97
>   (97024002)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
>   Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
>   Number of query rows: 20 out of 50000
>   Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
>   Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
>   Number of DML rows: 20 out of 10000
>   Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
>   Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
>   Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
>   Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
>   Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
>   Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
>   Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
>
> 11:07:44.97 (97024002)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
>
> 11:07:44.0
>   (97056499)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|ClassTester.test_AccountChangeReporter
>   11:07:44.0 (97964501)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

---

It seems to indicate success, but the table is still empty,  even if I remove the upsert statement and change it to an insert instead.

the fields being inserted are defined as...

- `lastSunProcessed__c` is a Date/Time field
- `name__c` is a text(64) field
- `source__c` is a Picklist of 'Contact' or 'Account' (which actually did create an error if I put a wrong value in)
- `sourceId__c` is a text(18) field -- which should be long enough to hold any record ID
- `status__c` is also a Picklist of 'New', 'Changed', or 'Deleted'

Everything in the debug log looks good,  no errors,  but no records ever get inserted.

All I can think of is there's some configuration value somewhere I forgot to set, somewhere.

Comment: I find that debugs and exceptions tend to behave kinda funny in async execution contexts. For testing purposes, I'd suggest passing a null to the execute method (i.e. `AccountChangeReporter.execute(null)` rather than `System.enqueueJob(new AccountChangeReporter())`) if you're not doing that already. It also might help if you remove the try/catch for testing through execute anonymous (and just let the exception halt execution).

Comment: You could also do a `Database.insert()` command and then iterate through the `Database.SaveResult` objects one by one to see what errors are saved.  Also check to see if there are any triggers that could be blocking the transaction.  More info on `Database.insert` here:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database.htm

Comment: Also, for those not aware (I didn't know this myself until just now), `upsert acrRecs sourceId__c;` is not a typo. Upsert can take 2 "arguments", the second one tells the upsert which field to use in determining whether or not a record needs to be inserted or updated. [Relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm?search_text=upsert)

Comment: You run it as a test function, so a proper Apex unit test? Do you mean the table is empty when you examine it manually afterwards, or are you querying it in the same test execution? Just to rule out the obvious: test data DML is always rolled back after execution

Comment: You should *never* use an empty catch bock, and `debug` only blocks are empty as they don't perform any follow up action. You're swallowing the exception here. I recommend you remove the `try`/`catch` entirely.

Comment: This is running as a test in the debug console using this class:

Comment: woops! This is running as a test function in the debug console using this class and being called from the test menu
<pre>
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class ClassTester {

//    static testMethod void test_PickListCounter() {
//        PickListCounter.doCount();
//    }
    
    static testMethod void test_AccountChangeReporter() {
        AccountChangeReporter acr = new AccountChangeReporter();
        acr.execute(null);
    }
}
</pre>

Catch block isn't empty, it's calling System.debug, printing the e.getMessage() result, which never gets hit, so nothing got caught.

Comment: I knew that wasn't going to work :)  Anyway I see two good tests to try, checking the .SaveResults and trying anonymous console.

Comment: Yeah, the formatting options for comments are quite limited. Things like that are better off as an [edit] to your original question.

Comment: So, progress!  Looks like execute anonymous is working!  but as Stephen.B said above, as a unit test it must be getting rolled back.   (Wish the log had displayed that!)  Anyway that gets me past the stumbling block, thanks for the help!